# Powershell - Rename files preserving part of the name + checksum

Tags: powershell

I have some long filenames that potensially can cause issues with Windows path max chars, and I would like to rename them preserving part of it - and also adding a RNG 4 letter/digit combination.

Filename example:  `478432_1400_79834_SomeKindofText_UserInputSoItCanBeReallyLongCombinedWithANetworkPath.jpg`
Wanted rename outcome:
`478432_1400_79834_SomeKindofText_abc1.jpg`
Where 'abc1' represents the 4 letter/digit combination of a checksum

This is the code I have so far:

```
$search_folder = "C:\PS\Test\"

Get-ChildItem $search_folder -File | ForEach-Object {
    $checksum = Get-FileHash -Path $_
    $checksum = $checksum.substring(0,3)
    Rename-Item -NewName { $search_folder+$_.BaseName.Split('_')[0..3] + $checksum + $_.Extension }
}
```

My first problem is that `Get-FileHash` does not support substring method, generating a error message:

> ```
> Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Powershell.Utility.FileHash] does not contain a method named 'substring'.
> ```

My second problem is that it tries to do a Resolve-Path in my current PS shell directory instead of $search_folder

My third problem is that the underscores in the filename is not preserved, so a -WhatIf tag on the Rename-Item method yields a result like "478432 1400 79834 SomeKindofText"

Tips or suggestions would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first problem is that Get-FileHash does not support substring method, generating a error message:
>
> > ```
> > Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Powershell.Utility.FileHash] does not contain a method named 'substring'.
> > ```

`$checksum` does not store the hash string, it stores an *object* that has a property named `Hash`, which in turn stores the string you want, so change this line:

```
$checksum = $checksum.substring(0,3)
```

To:

```
$checksum = $checksum.Hash.Substring(0,3)
```

---

> My second problem is that it tries to do a Resolve-Path in my current PS shell directory instead of $search_folder

Two general solutions to this problem:

1. Pass the absolute path to the file explicitly:

   ```
   Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName { ... }
   ```
2. Or pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Rename-Item` and let PowerShell bind the path correctly:

   ```
   $_ |Rename-Item -NewName { ... }
   ```

---

> My third problem is that the underscores in the filename is not preserved, so a -WhatIf tag on the Rename-Item method yields a result like "478432 1400 79834 SomeKindofText"

Splitting a string on `'_'` will also remove the underscores - to reverse this, use `'_'` as a delimiter in a `-join` operation:

```
$firstFourPartsOfBaseName = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0..3] -join '_'
```

---

Putting this all together, we get:

```
$search_folder = "C:\PS\Test\"

Get-ChildItem $search_folder -File | ForEach-Object {
    $checksum = Get-FileHash -Path $_
    $checksum = $checksum.hash.substring(0,3)
    $_ |Rename-Item -NewName { 
        # calculate new base name ("478432_1400_79834_SomeKindofText_abc1")
        $newBasename = @($_.BaseName.Split('_')[0..3]; $checksum) -join ''
        # add extension and output
        $newBasename,$_.Extension -join '.'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see your script adjusted below:

```
$search_folder = "C:\PS\Test\"

Get-ChildItem $search_folder -File | ForEach-Object {
    $checksum = Get-FileHash -Path $_
    $checksum = $checksum.hash.substring(0,3)
    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($search_folder + $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0..3] + $checksum + $_.Extension)
}
```

You were trying to get a sub string of an object, using the property `hash` on `$Checksum` will allow you to create a substring.

I have also added `-path` to the `rename-item` request and changed the parenthesis on the string construction (it could be either of these that were causing you an issue, unfortunately I haven't tested this.)